# How to @Autowire generic type to inner generic class' bean without xml configuration?

Tags: spring, generic-type-argument

I have a generic class DefaultBatchReportService.
I want to pass different POJO class, Service & Dao into this generic class.

However, I find difficulties in passing specific classes to generic abstract class with inner autowired generic class.

I got errors as following:

> Feb 02, 2016 1:49:10 PM
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager
>
> Feb 02, 2016 1:49:10 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase
>   execute WARNING: Error creating bean with name 'rt001Bean': Injection
>   of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.edgar.report.core.DefaultBatchReportService
>   com.edgar.test.RT001Bean.bReportController; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'defaultBatchReportService': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.edgar.report.core.SingleReportService
>   com.edgar.report.core.DefaultBatchReportService.singleReportService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.edgar.report.core.SingleReportService] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: RT001Service,
>   RT002Service, RT003Service
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'rt001Bean': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.edgar.report.core.DefaultBatchReportService
>   com.edgar.test.RT001Bean.bReportController; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'defaultBatchReportService': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.edgar.report.core.SingleReportService
>   com.edgar.report.core.DefaultBatchReportService.singleReportService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.edgar.report.core.SingleReportService] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 3:
>   RT001Service,RT002Service,RT003Service    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:342)
>     at com.gitgub.javaplugs.jsf.ViewScope.get(ViewScope.java:69)    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:55)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:93)    at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:259)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     at
>   com.edgar.bean.MDCFilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(MDCFilterSecurityInterceptor.java:24)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

## Batch Report Service:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class DefaultBatchReportService <T extends SingleReportService, I extends ReportInputParam, M extends ReportMeta, MD extends ReportMetaDetail, C extends ReportContent, P extends ReportDao<I , M, MD, C>> {
    @Setter
    private I inputParam;
    @Setter
    private M meta;

    @Autowired
    @Setter
    private T singleReportService;
    @Autowired
    @Setter
    private P reportDao; 
}
```

## Managed Bean Class:

```
@Component
@SpringScopeView
@Getter
@Setter
public class RT001Bean extends BaseBean {
    @Autowired
    private DefaultBatchReportService<RT001Service, RT001_InputParam, RT001_Meta, RT001_Meta.Detail, RT001_Content, RT001Dao> bReportController;

    private RT001_InputParam inputParam;

    public void generateBatchReport() {

        //Start Report Generation
        try {
            bReportController.doSomething(inputParam);
            ....
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            // Print Error Message

    }
}
```

In this project, my team is using JSF-Spring integrated framework. Normal standard injection of controls works fine (without Generic Types).

There are more than one Batch Report with same procedures in my project, thats why I want to use DefaultBatchReportService to handle every BatchReport by passing different class to it. (RT001..., RT002..., RT003..) Then, developers can focus on drawing the 'single' report.

Sorry for my poor English :/

Comment: This is a very long question - can you boil it down a bit to make it less laborious to understand?

Comment: From exception I would suspect the *NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.edgar.report.core.SingleReportService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: RT001Service, RT002Service, RT003Service* is the critical error.

Comment: @FritzDuchardt Well, I'm sorry for that. To simply, I want to create a Generic Service (DefaultBatchService) that intakes Specific Service & Dao & POJO (RT001....) in order to function. However, seems I cannot autowire everything well.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I found that too! but I do have many RT00x service to be used by DefaultBatchReportService. I specified which Service in the ManagedBean class already, seems Spring cannot see that.